Protect stored procedure from schema changes
I want to protect a SQL Server stored procedure from changes to the underlying tables.
As you can see in the test below, I am able to break this stored procedure with no warning or errors.
Ideally I would like an internal SQL Server solution where the 'drop column' line fails due to dependencies, similar to trying to drop a table with foreign keys. This would force the developer to also fix the stored procedure or reconsider their approach.
I could protect this with some automated tests but it feels like an ambulance at the bottom of the cliff.
Any advice is appreciated.
--Create two column table with one row of data

CREATE TABLE test.testTable (c1 int, c2 int)

INSERT INTO test.testTable 
VALUES (1, 2)
GO

--create procedure to return second column    
CREATE PROCEDURE test.testProcedure 
AS
     SELECT c2 
     FROM test.testTable    
GO

--drop second column from table. This succeeds despite the dependency in the stored procedure.    
ALTER TABLE test.testTable DROP COLUMN c2

EXEC test.testProcedure

The call to the procedure fails:

Invalid column name 'c2'

How can I best protect this procedure to avoid bugs?

Does SCHEMABINDING work?

Schema Bound Stored Procedures do exist, but they have (very) strict rules.

You can't, so lots of automated tests (which you should have anyway) are the best way to know everything works.

Migrating the dev workflow to SSDT will cover most of these issues, but not all of them. Test deployment and test runs are your best friends here.

Even with clever code, you can't validate stuff like dynamic sql, where columns might be hidden behind some logic. At a previous place, we did a lot of DROP and RENAMEs, the only way to make it all work was automatic test of stored procedures (and we had thousands of them) and code review. You could do some cursory checks with sys.sql_expression_dependencies which at least gets your partways

Perhaps a procedure isn't what you actually need. Maybe a VIEW or FUNCTION with SCHEMABINDING would better serve your goal. The procedure above is obviously overly simplified, so doesn't paint us a true picture of what you're trying to achieve here.

These are useful comments, it seems schemabinding might be what I am after, and the 'stored procedure' is not a hard requirement, I also have functions with the same problem. I am learning!

it's not possible in general case.
your procedure can compute required columns in runtime. so there is no way to statically analyze what db structures are needed for it.
u can bind the procedure to some structures manually (some smart trigger on alter table) so that you'll get error when those structures are being modified/deleted. but that's a duplication (prone to human error) and it's a lot of work.
regardless of the above you should have some tests that ensures your software is working as expected. one of those tests should trigger that procedure at some point. then u have failed test that prevents you from commiting / merging faulty code. and usually there is no other way, it's just runtime tools are more powerful than static analysis

A best practice approach that will solve this is to have your database maintained via a "database project" in "Visual Studio".
Database will not "build" if you make a mistake that breaks a procedure. Since you mention that there is a "developer" involved then it will seem very natural for them to fix just like code that does not compile.

Personally, I prefer SSDT Database projects, when feasible, as mentioned in the answer by Thomas Koelle.
This does not directly answer your question; however, it does offer an alternative.
You can iterate all of your stored procedures and in the iteration make a call to sp_refreshsqlmodeule. This procedure will raise an exception or return non-zero if the procedure does not compile.
There are some edge cases. One example is that dynamic sql does not get validated.
Perhaps running a process like this periodically will get close to your goal.
DECLARE @ProcName NVARCHAR(150)
DECLARE @Result INT
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE X CURSOR FOR  
    SELECT ROUTINE_SCHEMA+'.'+ROUTINE_NAME AS ProcedureName 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES WHERE ROUTINE_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE'
OPEN X
FETCH NEXT FROM X INTO @ProcName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @SQL = 'EXEC sp_refreshsqlmodule '''+@ProcName+''''
    BEGIN TRY
        EXEC @Result = sp_executesql @SQL
        IF(@Result<>0)
            RAISERROR('does not compile', 16, 1);   
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        PRINT @ProcName+' - '+ERROR_MESSAGE()
    END CATCH

    FETCH NEXT FROM X INTO @ProcName
END

CLOSE X
DEALLOCATE X

